# How to chain reactive operations after empty Mono without blocking?

Tags: reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

Basically what I am trying to achieve is to call a second repository (a `ReactiveCrudRepository`) or throw an exception, depending on the result of a call to a first repository.

My original idea looks like this:

```java
/** Reactive with blocking code */
public Flux<SecondThing> getThings(String firstThingName) {
    FirstThing firstThing = firstRepo
        .findByName(firstThingName)
        // Warning: "Inappropriate blocking method call"
        .blockOptional()  // this fails in test-context
        .orElseThrow(() -> new FirstThingNotFound(firstThingName));

    return secondRepo.findAllByFirstThingId(firstThing.getId());
}
```

Which would correspond to the following non-reactive approach:

```java
/** Non-reactive */
public List<SecondThing> getThings(String firstThingName) {
    FirstThing firstThing = firstRepo
        .findByName(firstThingName)
        .orElseThrow(() -> new FirstThingNotFound(firstThingName));

    return secondRepo.findAllByFirstThingId(firstThing.getId());
}
```

I haven't found a way to do this in a reactive non-blocking way. All I need is to throw an error if an empty `Mono` comes out of the first call, and continue the pipeline if not empty; but I could not seem to use `onErrorStop` or `doOnError` correctly here, and `map` does not help as it skips the empty `Mono`.

What I have is a workaround if I use `id` instead of `name`, but I'm not quite satisfied with it as it shows a different behaviour in the case where is an instance of `FirstThing` but no `SecondThing` linked to it:

```java
/** Reactive workaround 1 */
public Flux<SecondThing> getThings(Long firstThingId) {
    return secondRepo
        .findAllByFirstThingId(firstThingId)
        .switchIfEmpty(
            Flux.error(() -> new FirstThingNotFound(firstThingName))
        );
}
```

Another workaround I've found is the following, that replaces the empty `Mono` with a `null` value, but it doesn't look right and throws a warning too:

```java
/** Reactive workaround 2 */
public Flux<SecondThing> getThings(String firstThingName) {
    return firstRepo
        .findByName(firstThingName)
        // Warning: "Passing 'null' argument to parameter annotated as @NotNull"
        .defaultIfEmpty(null)
        .flatMapMany(
            firstThing -> secondRepo.findAllByFirstThingId(firstThing.getId()
        )
        .onErrorMap(
            NullPointerException.class, e -> new FirstThingNotFound(firstThingName)
        );
}
```

What is **the correct way to chain the calls to both repositories** so that the presence or absence of a `FirstThing` with the requested `firstThingName` conditions the call to the second repo?

Comment: Didn't look too closely but be aware that a reactive flow doesn't continue if it is empty. So, it seems to me you could just call get firstThingName and if it comes back empty it won't make the call to getFirstThing so is there a problem?

Comment: @K.Nicholas the problem is, I'd like to throw an exception when no FirstThing is found. So I guess one could rephrase my question to: "How to map to error from empty Mono?"

Comment: Well, if the firstRepo returns an Optional then you can do 'orElseThrow' . I think that's the cleanest answer. `.map(op->op.orElseThrow(()->new IllegalArgumentException("name not found")))`

Comment: @K.Nicholas Agreed, but the `ReactiveCrudRepository` returns a `Mono` and converting this to an `Optional` requires a blocking operation, which I'm trying to avoid. What you propose would need a `Mono<Optional<FirstThing>>` to work. Not possible in my case as the repository class is auto-generated, but I'll save the idea for som other time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a solution so simple, that I could be ashamed not to have found it earlier:

```java
public Flux<SecondThing> getThings(String firstThingName) {
    return firstRepo
        .findByName(firstThingName)
        .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(() -> new FirstThingNotFound(firstThingName)))
        .flatMapMany(
            firstThing -> secondRepo.findAllByFirstThingId(firstThing.getId()
        );
}
```

The trick is that `switchIfEmpty` does not force you to pick a "valid" replacement value, so it is possible to use a `Mono.error` to propagate the right exception directly.

Comment: i was just about to write this answer.... i was wondering why you were complicating things so much. And so you know null is not an allowed value in webflux, so you should never pass null, and you should in theory never need to performe any nullchecks

Comment: @K.Nicholas optionals are usually pretty sparse needed in webflux, if you are returning an optional you are probably dealing with traditional blocking code. I would prefer reactive code returning `Mono<T>` alt. `Mono<Void>` to represent a `Maybe` instead of `Mono<Optional<T>>` which to me feels like an unnecessary double wrap.

Comment: @Toerktumlare yeah now I feel dumb for not finding this earlier :D I guess explaining the problem to strangers helps solving it! What do you mean by "null is not an allowed value in webflux"? Is it a convention to follow in order to avoid later problems, or will my compiler give me serious trouble?

Comment: well the reactive streams specification disallows null values in a sequence, so i would not recommend returning null, i dont know how hard Reactor follows the specification, but you will probably not have a good time with unexpected behaviour if you return null. Make it a good practice to either return a `Mono<T>` or a `Mono.empty()` from functions (`Mono<Void>`)

Comment: @Toerktumlare Got it. Thanks for your help!